# Back button corresponding to wrong navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have the following storyboard setup:

The left side are my log in controllers and the right is my user access view. On the right side, it is a `UITableViewController` leading to various `UIViewControllers`, however, when I press the back button on these views, they go instead to the login view controller, far to the left of the storyboard instead back to the `UITableViewController`.

I think it's something to do with the 2 `UINavigationControllers`, but can't find a solution.

Hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think after login screens you have to show your tab bar modally